# Play/pause on HTML5 video tag on Ionic Angular project

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

Hello i want to put a play/pause button in center on video tag.

```
<div id="video-container">
                        <video controls webkit-playsinline class="fillWidth" >
                            <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/webm" />
                            <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/mp4">
                            <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/ogg">
                            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                        </video>
                        </div>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use ViewChild.
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rw7xf4)

```
<video controls webkit-playsinline class="fillWidth" #video >
     <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/webm" />
     <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/ogg">
     Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<a (click)="playVideo()">Play</a>
<a (click)="stopVideo()">Pause</a>
```

in component

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';


@ViewChild('video') myVideo: ElementRef;
```

give function to your buttons below

```
playVideo(){
    this.myVideo.nativeElement.play();
  }
stopVideo(){
    this.myVideo.nativeElement.pause();
  }
```

Comment: import { Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';  @ViewChild('video') myVideo: ElementRef; i am getting an error on ElementRef

Comment: I wrote import that whicg ones will u import to your component.ts ViewChild, ElementRef

Comment: i see the demo. Why doesn't play when i press the center play button. In the photo i put

Comment: Can u create your demo in stackblitz? Then I can see the problem

Comment: ok i done it now i have to hide show the play button. But why doesn't it play the center play button that it appears by default? in your demo it does

Comment: https://angular-fq6ssd.stackblitz.io but in mine machine doesn't play the center play button. Do i have to do install a node_module? I use Ionic 3 Angular 5

Comment: OK my problem is that i put put button and text over the video tag so it doesnt play the center button. Any way around it?

Comment: Did u give click function to it ?

Comment: ok it starts but if i want to pause? i put it on first div no <video>

Comment: Can u open my demo in answe I editted click function. U can create one more attribute which is boolean then with this boolean u can play or pause

Comment: Thats it. Only one thing if you have a link to go to another page when you press it it triggers the function also. Stops or starts the video even if you only want to press the link.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble man, because there are nore than one videos it only plays the first one.